# how to use populate method with react and node.js?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongoose-populate

i have two collection in my db "users" and "forms"

each user has a table of forms

i used populate method to do this and it works

this is the model of user:

```js
const Schema = mongoose.Schema


const UserSchema = new Schema({
    firstName: {
        type: 'string',
        required: ' Firstname is Required'
    },
    lastName: {
        type: 'string',
        required: ' lastName is Required'
    },
    email: {
        type: 'string',
        required: ' email is Required'
    },
    phone: {
        type: 'string',

    },
    entrprise: {
        type: 'string'
    },
    password: {
        type: 'string',
        required: ' password is Required'
    },
    forms: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Form"
    }

    ]
})

const User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema)
module.exports = User
```

this the model of form

```js
const Schema = mongoose.Schema

const FormSchema = new Schema({

    logo: {
        type: String,

    },
    compagnyName: {
        type: String,

    },
    title: {
        type: String,


    },
    description: {
        type: String,

    },
    userId: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    },
    cardQuestion: [
        {
            questionTitle: String,
            questionType: String,
            questionCourte: String,
            questionLongue: String,
            choixMultiple: String,
            caseaCocher: String,
            telechargerFichier: String,
            date: Date,
            heure: String,
            delete: false,
            obligatoire: false,
        }
    ]

})
const Form = mongoose.model('Form', FormSchema)
module.exports = Form
```

and this is how i use populate method

```js
const getUser = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const { userId } = req.params;
        if (!userId) return res.status(400).json({ message: "ERROR ID!" });
        const result = await User
            .findById(userId).populate('forms')

            .exec()

        return res.status(200).json({ message: "Success", result });
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).json({ message: "INTERNAL ERROR SERVER!" });
        console.log(err.message);
    }
};
```

i added a user with forms using postman with the post method

when i try to add a form with react

```js
const response = await axios.post(`${API_URL}/form/:userId`,
            {
                ...form,
                userId: localStorage.getItem('userId')
            },
            {
                headers: {
                    authorization: localStorage.getItem('userId')
                }
            }
```

i get the form with the user id like this:

```html
 {
        "_id": "6022916bf1d1060f84bc17d0",
        "compagnyName": "axa",
        "description": "recruitement",
        "userId": "60214c5ec0491fcb2d8c29e8",
        "__v": 0,
        "cardQuestion": []
    },
```

i find the new form in the forms collection but when i get the user ,the forms field doesn't update (still empty if i don't add the table of forms manually)

```html
  "result": {
        "forms": [],
        "_id": "60214c5ec0491fcb2d8c29e8",
        "firstName": "moon",
        "lastName": "lea",
        "email": "moon15@gmail.com",
        "password": "$2b$10$bnH0cEBQKktgaKHfBac3L.xUUNEYt9HaqKdLKxLOERrHPG4MVPPFS",
        "phone": "087654266377",
        "__v": 0
    }
}
```

this is how i add a user

```js
const register = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const { firstName, lastName, email, phone, password, forms } = req.body
        if (!firstName || !lastName || !email || !phone || !password)
            return res.status(400).json({ message: 'ERROR!' })


        //CHECKING EXISTING USER
        const found = await User.findOne({ email })
        console.log(found)
        if (found) return res.status(400).json({ message: 'Email already exist' })
        console.log(found)

        //HASHING THE PASSWORD
        const hashPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, saltRounds)
        console.log(hashPassword)

        //CREATING THE NEW USER
        const newUser = new User()
        newUser.firstName = firstName
        newUser.lastName = lastName
        newUser.email = email
        newUser.password = hashPassword
        if (phone) newUser.phone = phone
        if (forms) newUser.forms = forms
        console.log('i')

        //SAVING THE NEW USER
        const result = await newUser.save()
        console.log(result)
        if (!result) return res.status(400).json({ message: 'failed to create user' })
```

can someone help?

Comment: yes sure

const Schema = mongoose.Schema

const FormSchema = new Schema({

    logo: {
        type: String,

    },
    compagnyName: {
        type: String,

    },
    title: {
        type: String,


    },
    description: {
        type: String,

    },
    userId: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
}

})
const Form = mongoose.model('Form', FormSchema)
module.exports = Form

Comment: yes it's in the question

Comment: Hi @MounaSis, i think that the problem here is that you are saving a Form, with userId as ref, but you're querying User, asking to populate the form ref (that doesn't exists, based on the code that you've added).
Have you tried to query the form, populating the userId?

Comment: hello, you're right thank you i correct this, but the issue is not here
my issu is when i add form in frontend i can't see it in the result i get an empty array

Comment: @Yousaf i added it

Comment: i added it here 
 const { firstName, lastName, email, phone, password, forms } = req.body

Comment: There's one issue that i see in you schema design. There's a circular dependency between `User` and `Form` models. In my opinion, you can get rid of `forms` field in `User` schema and only keep user reference in `Form` schema. This will help you create a user first and then create a `Form` that is associated with that user.

Comment: if i do this, then how can i get all forms of a specific user in node and react?

Comment: You can use [virtual populate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#populate-virtuals)

Comment: do you think that virtual populate is better in my case?

Comment: If the number of forms associated with any particular user are fixed, then it is ok to keep their reference in the user schema but if the number of forms is not fixed and could grow indefinitely, then, instead of user documents keeping a reference to their forms, you should have each form reference the user it is associated with and if you do this, then you need to use [virtual populate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#populate-virtuals) to get the forms associated with a particular user.

Comment: i referenced to the user into the form model and i used populate, and it works, thank you a lot

Answer (score 0):

maybe you have to change .populate('forms') in getUser to .populate('form')
i think it save it in singular shape